# Where is the documentation for the nth package

Tags: packages

The ctan entry has no documentation and `texdoc nth` does not find an entry.

Any idea where to find documentation for the package options?

Comment: `texdoc nth` works fine for me on `TL2012` (on linux)

Comment: `texdoc nth` on TL2012 (mac) opens up a README file for the `turnthepage` package.  Strange.  `texdoc nth.sty` works just fine.

Comment: Maybe it's a conspiration aimed at hiding this package. Now that you found it, *don't* use it. There are *many* good reasons not to use a "superscript th" for ordinal numbers.

Comment: @egreg What are those reasons? Why should I not use superscript th for ordinals?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You find the documentation inside the package file `nth.sty` right at the beginning.

Also `texdoc` can be used, but the file name extension has to be given:

```
texdoc nth.sty
```